# How to deal with this SQL injection warning (CA2100)

Tags: sql, .net, sql-injection, ca2202

Below is the code I got from Microsoft page: [SqlCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public static Int32 ExecuteNonQuery(String connectionString, String commandText, CommandType commandType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(commandText, conn))
            {
                // There're three command types: StoredProcedure, Text, TableDirect. The TableDirect 
                // type is only for OLE DB.  
                cmd.CommandType = commandType;
                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

                conn.Open();
                return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
}
```

However, VS code analysis still complains about "CA2100":

> Warning   CA2100  The query string passed to 'SqlCommand.SqlCommand(string, SqlConnection)' in 'FlexClaimFormRepository.ExecuteNonQuery(string, string, CommandType, params SqlParameter[])' could contain the following variables 'commandText'. If any of these variables could come from user input, consider using a stored procedure or a parameterized SQL query instead of building the query with string concatenations.

I know the exact reason why the warning is there, but anyidea on how to get rid of it? Given setting commandText inside the function is not acceptable since I want it to be a parameter.

Comment: Apologize, it's CA2100. I already updated the title.

Comment: OK. Show us sample query. In a meanwhile, please see: [CA2100: Review SQL queries for security vulnerabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182310.aspx)

Comment: I don' think we need sample query here since VS code analysis will just give the same warning.

Comment: When you are sure that the command is not coming from a user input or from another kind of "outside", you can safely suppress it.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger Is there anything I can do where the system needs to run SQL script from internal user(s)?

Comment: If `commandText` is free text that can be filled with arbitrary SQL like `UPDATE Salary SET Amount = Amount * 1000 WHERE Person='Me'`, then the best thing to do is ensure this application only ever connects with a read only user. For example by adding the user to the `db_datareader` role. VS code analysis won't recognise that though.

Comment: The CA2100 description says "It is safe to suppress a warning from this rule if the command text does not contain any user input."

Comment: @TobyD: I don't know what you mean by "internal user(s)". Is it a client-server application or are there processes running under different users? Then you have to make sure that no strings coming from the client are directly used to build a query. You are passing a connection string to ExecuteNonQuery. Where is it coming from? Can a regular user get the connection string (containing a password) and access the database directly? If yes then you cannot be safe from malicious changes anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but maybe this will help someone with the same issue. I also was using a stored procedure and therefore suppressed the warning using the information from this article from Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/in-source-suppression-overview?view=vs-2019 .

Here's the attribute I added to my method:

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Security", "CA2100:Review SQL queries for security vulnerabilities", Justification = "Method already uses a Stored Procedure")]
```